# Python CGI Error

Tags: python, cgi

I have a `test.py` in my `cgi-bin` folder on my webserver, and when I run it I get a `500 Internal Server Error`. What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"
print "hi"
```

What permissions do I need to have?

Comment: Is your script executable? (chmod +x test.py)?
Does python really in /usr/bin/python? (how is apach configured)
What happens when you run the script from the command line?

Comment: Give more information. Which webserver are you using? Apache? Which user is it running under? What do you got in logs? What are your files permission?

Comment: Script is executable, Python is there, not sure how Apache is configured, runs fine on command line. Using Webfaction, not sure what logs to check, permissions are 755 ATM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't produce valid HTTP output. The HTTP specification requires two characters per line ending `\r\n`.

Also try running the script from a shell. Also look at any debug logs from the server.

Comment: Did all that but the logs; no idea where they are. Still not working.

Comment: Try looking in `/var/log/httpd`, or somewhere under `/var/log`.

Answer (score 1):

To effectively add an empty line to mark the end of header lines,
use CR-LF line endings:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print "Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
print "hi"
```

Or, without ugly backslashes and adding an empty `print` statemanet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print "Content-type: text/plain"
print
print "hi"
```

Comment: Works for me, try an empty print instead of control characters.